# hide element but not nested child with css only

Tags: css, hide, amp-html, google-amp

I have something like that in an AMP-Page (I cant change the structure as its given and `!important` is not possible for AMP):

```
<p class="test">hide me <a>show me</a></p>
```

How can I achieve hiding the html of the parent bot not the nested a-tag?
I tried this without success:

```
.test{display:none;}
.test a{display:block;}
```

and also:

```
.test:not(a){display:none;}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `font-size`?

```css
.test {
  font-size: 0;
}

.test a {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<p class="test">hide me <a>show me</a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using hidden and visible properties it is possible.

.test {visibility: hidden;}
a {visibility: visible;}

Comment: That'll still takes place